# Using different entry point beside main in vulkan

Tags: glsl, vulkan

I know when creating shader module in Vulkan you can specify the entry point in `VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo` using `pName`.

However, I haven't been able to use another entry point but 'main' in my glsl/spv file.

```
typedef struct VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo {
  VkStructureType                     sType;
  const void*                         pNext;
  VkPipelineShaderStageCreateFlags    flags;
  VkShaderStageFlagBits               stage;
  VkShaderModule                      module;
  const char*                         pName;
  const VkSpecializationInfo*         pSpecializationInfo;
} VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo;
```

Has anyone ever use this feature and can give me an example? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was trying it some way back and I believe this is not currently possible using the official `glslc` or `glslangValidator`.

Note GLSL mandates a `main` function, so the autors probably found it unuseful.

`glslc` outright says that relevant parameter works only for HLSL.

`glslangValidator` is less clear, but relevant parameters are (in the time of writing) ignored when GLSL is used.

UPDATE:
There is a [relevant GitHub Issue](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glslang/issues/1045). And this feature got supported. So you have to either wait for next SDK release, or build the compiler from `master`.

Indeed testing that version it works with:

```
glslangValidator.exe -V -H -e mymain --source-entrypoint main -o hello.spv hello.vert
```

The compiler logs an error if non-`main` function is used in GLSL, but it seems to work anyway:

```
glslangValidator.exe -V -H -e mymain --source-entrypoint sourcemain -o hello.spv hello.vert
```